# Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY' in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe, browser

Everytime I try give my local address of the html file in iframe's src, it gives the error in console

**Error**

```
Refused to display 'url' in a frame  because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY
```

Though there are some solutions, but they have solution in php or c#,
I am using AngularJs, and I am very new to this.

Comment: Angular is a client side framework. It has no effect on what HTTP headers the server responsible for 'url' sends and is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: So by your opinion what are the possible solutions

Comment: Configure the server hosting 'url' to sent a different X-Frame-Options header.

Comment: well rite now I am using intellij for development puropse, so can we configure anything there. I am totally blank over here, I never get this error in visual studion.

Comment: I thought intellij was an editor. Does it have some sort of built-in webserver? You should check its documentation to figure out how to stop it from banning you from using frames.

Comment: yes it is an editor, but we can configure web server to it, as I am using java for db connection, I have configured it with tomcat. Well never thought it will go this way.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with meta tag.
Setting the meta tag is useless. For instance,

`<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">`

has no effect. Do not use it!

Only by setting through the HTTP header like the examples below, X-Frame-Options will work.

To configure Apache to send the X-Frame-Options header for all pages, add this to your site's configuration:

> Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

To configure Apache to set the X-Frame-Options  deny , add this to your site's configuration:

> Header set X-Frame-Options DENY

To configure Apache to set the X-Frame-Options  to ALLOW-FROM a specific Host , add this to your site's configuration:

> Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/"

Answer (score -2):

Please add this meta tag on html page to resolve this issue

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="sameorigin">
```

Comment: `meta http-equiv` is a joke, it isn't really equivalent to HTTP headers, and that won't do anything